# How to pass form data to GAS

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to pass data from a form into a Google Apps Script but when I press submit I am greeted by I blank screen.

Form:

```html
<div id="nameDiv">
  <form action="https://script.google.com/a/umbc.edu/macros/s/AKfycbztum1ImJZeXXYt0fFhwOAMUsB5zCsJQohrum4W7qiH/dev">
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname">

    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" >

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="google.script.run.nameSearch()">
  </form>
</div>
```

Script:

```js
function nameSearch(){
  try {
    var firstName = document.getElementById("fname").value
    var lastName = document.getElementById("lname").value
    var inputSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z3j7wxMLsXilyKDIH7XnE7VNQqF66fIH4B-mmuWwCJ8/edit#gid=1235654559");
    var inputData = inputSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    for (var i = 1; i < inputData.length; i++) {
      if (inputData[i][10] == firstName && inputData[i][11] == lastName) {
        var result = inputData[i][14] + ": " + inputData[i][15]
      }
    }
    document.getElementById('nameDiv').innerHTML = 
                "<center>Last Name:" + lastName + "</center>" +
                "</br><center>First Name:" + firstName + "</center>"
  } catch(e) {
    alert(e)
  }
}
```

I am trying to pass this data to the script so that it can use it to search a google sheet so I cannot just place the script in the html as a client side script. Any thought?

Comment: You're mixing server and client  abilities. Kindly read the official documentation on client server interactions and practice the examples there first.

Comment: All the HTML-related methods (`getElementById`, innerHTML`, etc.) should be in client-side script, and Apps Script methods in the server-side. I'd provide a fixed script, but I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve here. What's the purpose of the variable `result`? Please consider providing a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, as well as explaining the desired outcome.

Comment: @iamblichus thank you for the helpful information, I am trying to display information from a google sheets spreadsheet onto my web app, that is what I was trying to do with ```result```  is there a way to pass ```document.getElementById("fname").value``` to the server side code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the HTML-related methods (`getElementById`, `innerHTML`, etc.) should be in client-side script, and Apps Script methods should be in the server-side.

If I understand you correctly, you want to do the following:

- When this form gets submitted, look for the row whose columns K and L match the inputted fields (indexes 10 and 11 from `inputData` array).
- For this row, return data from columns O and P (indexes 14 and 15 from `inputData` array).
- Write this returned data to the HTML.

If all this is correct, then you could do this:

- Add an onclick event in the submit input that will fire a client-side function (a function that is declared inside the  tags in the HTML). There is no need to use a  for this. The HTML body could be something like this:

```html
<div id="nameDiv">
  <label for="fname">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname">

  <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" >

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="clientNameSearch()">
</div>
```

- From this client-side function called `clientNameSearch()`, retrieve the values from `fname` and `lname`, and use these as parameters when you call a server-side function called `nameSearch`):

```js
function clientNameSearch() {
  var firstName = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  var lastName = document.getElementById("lname").value;
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).nameSearch(firstName, lastName);
}
```

- This server-side function iterates through all rows with content in the spreadsheet, and returns the `result` for the first row whose columns K and L match the inputted data:

```js
function nameSearch(firstName, lastName){
  try {
    var inputSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z3j7wxMLsXilyKDIH7XnE7VNQqF66fIH4B-mmuWwCJ8/edit#gid=1235654559");
    var inputData = inputSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    for (var i = 1; i < inputData.length; i++) {
      if (inputData[i][10] == firstName && inputData[i][11] == lastName) {
        var result = inputData[i][14] + ": " + inputData[i][15];
        return result;
      }
    }
  } catch(e) {
    alert(e)
  }
}
```

This `result` is then passed as a parameter to a client-side function called `onSuccess` via [a success handler](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#myFunction(...)). This is necessary since server-side functions called by `google.script.run` don't return anything directly, as specified [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#myFunction(...)). Then `onSuccess` writes the `result` to the HTML:

```js
function onSuccess(result) {
  document.getElementById('nameDiv').innerHTML = "<div>" + result + "</div>";
}
```

#### Full code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="nameDiv">
      <label for="fname">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname">
      <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" >
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="clientNameSearch()">
   </div>
  </body>
  <script>
    function clientNameSearch() {
      var firstName = document.getElementById("fname").value;
      var lastName = document.getElementById("lname").value;
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).nameSearch(firstName, lastName);
    }
    function onSuccess(result) {
      document.getElementById('nameDiv').innerHTML = "<div>" + result + "</div>";
    }  
  </script>
</html>
```

And the `Code.gs` would be like:

```js
function nameSearch(firstName, lastName){
  try {
    var inputSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z3j7wxMLsXilyKDIH7XnE7VNQqF66fIH4B-mmuWwCJ8/edit#gid=1235654559");
    var inputData = inputSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    for (var i = 1; i < inputData.length; i++) {
      if (inputData[i][10] == firstName && inputData[i][11] == lastName) {
        var result = inputData[i][14] + ": " + inputData[i][15];
        return result;
      }
    }
  } catch(e) {
    alert(e)
  }
}

function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("your-html-name");
}
```

I'm not sure you want to write the `result` to the HTML, but in any case, at this point it shouldn't be difficult to modify this so that it writes exactly what you want and where you want.

#### Reference:

- [google.script.run.myFunction(...) (any server-side function)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#myFunction(...))
- [withSuccessHandler(function)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#myFunction(...))

I hope this is of any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Launch the dialog fill the text boxes and click submit. The view logs and see the next dialog.

```
function launchADialog() {
  var html='<form><br /><input type="text" name="Name" /> Name: <br /><input type="text" name="Age" /> Age: <br />';
  html+='<select name="Children" ><option value="0">None</option><option value="1">One</option><option value="2">Two</option></select> Children:<br />';
  html+='<input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="google.script.run.processForm(this.parentNode);" /></form>';
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, "The Form");
}

function processForm(form) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(form));
  var s=Utilities.formatString('<br />Name: %s <br />Age:%s <br />Number Of Children: %s', form.Name, form.Age, form.Children);
  s+='<br /><input type="button" value="Close" onClick="google.script.host.close();" />';
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(s);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, "Form Data")
}
```