# Apps-script function with dynamic parameter

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I am testing the app script platform and I have a doubt when using this code called from HTML file:

```
JSON.parse(<?= JSON.stringify(getDataFromSheet("tyreUse", "valueSearched")); ?>);
```

If I set the string value directly it works.
If I try to pass a variable that is declared in  it does not recognize it. How can I pass a JS variable to the app script function like next example?

```
let value_searched = "cars";
JSON.parse(<?= JSON.stringify(getDataFromSheet("tyreUse", value_searched)); ?>);
```

Comment: Just in case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60011619/how-to-pass-form-data-to-gas

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: I'm exactly using this example but changing "temp" by variable value: https://netlabe.com/how-to-create-dashboard-for-free-with-google-sheets-and-chart-js-8c319ab8809b

Comment: This `JSON.parse(<?= JSON.stringify(getDataFromSheet("tyreUse", value_searched)); ?>);` is printing scriptlet in your HTML file, correct?  You need to set value_searched in Code.gs before you evaluate your template.  See this page https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#code.gs_5 toward the bottom.

Comment: There is no way to pass it from the client to the server side? with that parameter I can filter the results I want to get using a <select>html tag. I can't set it fixed value in the server side.

Comment: what's the error you can when replacing the text with the variable

Comment: render the data on your server (apps script) wouldn't work better, so you can make sure you're returning the data. I'd go with 
`let filteredValue = JSON.stringify(getDataFromSheet("tyreUse", value_searched)` and then send that to your template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of getting data from spreadsheet dynamically.  I typically build my page and then use an anonymous function of the form `(function () {}());` to get the data from spreadsheet and populate the HTML elements with the values.

Create an HTML file HTML_Demo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="A8SBwf" type="text">
    <input id="gNO89b" type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="buttonOnClick()">
    <script>
      function buttonOnClick() {
        try {
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler( 
            function(response) {
              document.getElementById("A8SBwf").value = response;
            }
          ).getCellA1();
        }
        catch(err) {
          alert(err);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then in Code.gs create the getCellA1:

```
function getCellA1() {
  try {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var range = sheet.getRange("A1");
    return range.getValue();
  }
  catch(err) {
    return err.message;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's just what I wanted. To complement your answer, here is the detailed information from google. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#page.html

Comment: @Pable, yes I do that when the css or script gets to be more complex

Answer (score 4):

Scriptlets like `<?= ?>` are used in html templates to load data from the server into html pages prior to rendering.  If you want to pass data back to a server side function then you can use google.script.run and there are restrictions on the data types that you can pass.

[google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)